# Why does the "onmouseover" event use "return true" to prevent default behavior?

Tags: javascript, events, onmouseover, event-handling

I have been searching for this for some time, but haven't got any explanation.

For "onclick" and other events in javascript, the event handler returning ***false*** means "prevent default action". However, there is one exception for "onmouseover". For "onmouseover", returning ***true*** means "prevent default action".

Why is there such a weird exceptional case for "onmouseover"?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using return **false** / **true** to prevent default event behaviour, use the default method / attribute on the event object:

```
elem.onmouseover = function(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event; // IE
    if(e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false; // IE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, returning `true` to prevent the url of a link to show up in the status bar is an IE-specific (mis-)feature. And trying to understand why IE does things the way it does is often a lost cause - just live with it...

Answer (score 2):

Who knows why really. Just the way it is:
you return TRUE from onmouseover to prevent url from appearing in the status bar, which would be the default behaviour indeed.